# css assignment using another object css in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have one `span` and one `textArea` In my asp.net code (c#) and this code works correctly:

`mySpan.Style.Value = myTextArea.Style.Value;`

Now my question is what code is equivalent in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a span with an ID of mySpan and a textarea with an ID of myTextArea,

```
$("#mySpan").html($("#myTextArea").val());
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, this answer assumes that you have a span with an ID of 'mySpan' and a textarea with an ID of 'myTextArea'. It sounds like in your situation, you may be dealing with C#/javascript interop. How are you communicating between the two?